# Deploy a SSIS package to remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to deploy a SSIS package to a remote SQL Server.
In the deployment wizard, when i want to create a new project with SQL Server Authentication, it gives me this error:

> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server
>   Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses
>   Integrated Authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27123)

As far as I understand, it is saying that I must use Windows Authentication and I don't know how I can use Windows Authentication in non Domain environment.

Comment: I have always had to a) log on to the server directly, b) use account that has admin rights (or explicit rights to msdb) c) run SSMS as admin while connecting to IS and d) make sure SSMS is the same version as IS on that machine. Never been able to do so remotely. I'll say "it's not possible" so someone will perhaps prove me wrong.

Comment: Have you tried the project deployment model? It can be deployed remotely.

Comment: Yes, I tried the project deployment too, the Deploying Packages Action fails with the same error.